# Unable to read the value from ssm using middy in nodejs

Tags: node.js, lambda, slack, aws-ssm, middy

Can someone help me with below code issue, For some reason. Lambda is giving me error

Log:

> {
> "errorType": "TypeError",
> "errorMessage": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Parameter')",
> "stack": [
> "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Parameter')",
> "    at /var/task/index.js:15922:46",
> "    at runMiddlewares (/var/task/index.js:15555:23)",
> "    at async runRequest (/var/task/index.js:15513:5)"
> ] }

Environment variable is set correctly, if i am hard coding the bot token here the code is working.

```
    // Require the Node Slack SDK package (github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk)
const { WebClient, LogLevel } = require("@slack/web-api");
import middy from '@middy/core'
import ssm from '@middy/ssm'
import doNotWaitForEmptyEventLoop from '@middy/do-not-wait-for-empty-event-loop'

const { BOT_TOKEN } = process.env;

if (!BOT_TOKEN) {
  throw new Error("BOT_TOKEN environment variable is not set");
}

let slackClient;
function initializeClient(botToken) {
  // WebClient instantiates a client that can call API methods
  // When using Bolt, you can use either `app.client` or the `client` passed to listeners.
  if (slackClient == undefined) {
    slackClient = new WebClient(botToken, {
      // LogLevel can be imported and used to make debugging simpler
      logLevel: LogLevel.DEBUG
    });
  }
  return slackClient;
}

const sendSlackNotification = async (message) => {
  const response = await slackClient.chat.postMessage({
    channel: process.env.SLACK_CHANNEL,
    text: message,
  });


  console.log(`Slack response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
};

async function handlePipelineEvent(event) {
  console.log(`Event: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
 
  const { detail } = event;
  const pipeline = detail.pipeline;
  const stage = detail.stage;
  const state = detail.state;

  let message;
  switch (state) {
    case "STARTED":
      message = `:Pipeline \`${pipeline}\` has started executing stage \`${stage}\``;
      break;
   
    default:
      message = `Pipeline ${pipeline} has changed state to ${state} on stage ${stage}`;
  }

  await sendSlackNotification(message);
  console.log('3');
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify("Slack notification sent successfully"),
  };
};

export const handler = middy(handlePipelineEvent).use(ssm({
  cache: true,
  cacheExpiryInMillis: 5 * 60 * 1000, // 5 minutes
  setToContext: true,
  names: {
    botToken: process.env.BOT_TOKEN
  }
})).before(async (handler) => {
  const botToken = handler.context.botToken.Parameter.Value;
  console.log(`Retrieved bot token: ${botToken}`);
  initializeClient(botToken);
});
```

Comment: Can you check the aws console for your Lambda and confirm that the BOT_TOKEN environment variable is correctly set. Go to the ```Configuration``` tab and then ```Environment variables``` section, see if  BOT_TOKEN is listed and has the value you expect.

Comment: the error is related to reading the Parameter property, but the provided code snippet doesn't include the part where the error occurs.

Comment: @bovop4 the error seems to occur in the callback used by before, he's trying to access the `Parameter` property from `botToken` but `botToken`  seems to be undefined

Comment: @djmonki The environment variables are correct